# With what changes would it be possible to first generate an animation frame and then execute the next code lines?

Tags: java, backup, loading, gif, desktop-application

I want to do is that It first generate the frame(Animator) and then go for next thing for which it is going

***Code are here***

```
 private void MHbackupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         // TODO add your handling code here:
        
new Animator().setVisible(true);

        String Dfrom =baseadd+"/"+user;
        String Dto = "E:/Backup" ;
       try {
            Dto = GetLine.mainn(baseadd+"/"+user+"/conf.txt", 3);
          System.out.println(Dto);
           File fl = new File(Dto);
           if(fl.exists()){
            Backup.main(Dfrom, Dto);
        this.requestFocus();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Backup saved successfully ");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
           }
           else{
               JLabel label = new JLabel("You not fixed any thing for backup so may fix any drive or external hard disk ");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
           }
        
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           JLabel label = new JLabel("You not fixed any thing for backup so may fix any drive or external hard disk ");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
           //Logger.getLogger(NewMenuH.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
       
    }
```

***Animator code are here***

```
public Animator() {
        initComponents();           //jbl is JLabel
        ImageIcon Loading = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Suthar\\Desktop\\GIF/ajax-loader.gif");
        jbl.setText("Loading ....");
        jbl.setIcon(Loading);
    }
```

My try is to ... Gif get visible as we clicked over the respective button
 but is not doing the same thing I generate the Animator Frame Visible but the Gif not Visible and the end thing that are in ButtonAction it get Visible . But i want to be First gif get visible and then go for other things.